# nokogiri : finding a node in html document by their styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am currently working in a web scrapping project with ruby on rails and below is the web-page link I am working on.

https://www.livelaw.in/top-stories/supreme-court-civil-suit-maintainable-jurisdiction-scope-sau-rajani-vs-sau-smita-2022-livelaw-sc-702-207475?infinitescroll=1

I have fetched all the (.story p ) from this page and particularly want to remove the last  tag having background-color:rgb(255,255,0) [Here's the thing I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V9El.jpg)

I want to select the  tag using the custom styling it has.
[picture for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnyWX.jpg)

I have tried everything and not able to do so. I there any other way I can select the desired text and remove it from the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usual attribute and you can get element by such selector

```
element = doc.at("b[style='background-color:rgb(255,255,0)']")
```

And to remove it

```
element.remove
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it works... give it a try

```rb
url = "https://www.livelaw.in/top-stories/supreme-court-civil-suit-maintainable-jurisdiction-scope-sau-rajani-vs-sau-smita-2022-liv"
elaw-sc-702-207475?infinitescroll=1")

file = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(URI.open(url))

element = file.xpath("//b[contains(@style,'background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0)')]")
```

Comment: idk why I tried this but it's returning me an empty array. But I found how to do it thanks a lot :).